# Hot to get the 'value' of the last element of type 'input' with a certain 'name'?

Tags: jquery, html

In my html page i have some fields like this, in this order:

```
< input type="hidden" name="foo" value="age:1">
< some other code >
< input type="hidden" name="foo" value="age:2">
< some other code >
<...>
< input type="hidden" name="foo" value="age:7">
```

In jquery how do I get 'age:7' that is the 'value' of the last element in page of type 'input' with a certain 'name' (without touching html!)?

I mean something like

```
$( "input[name='foo']" ).val()
```

but the last one found in page.

Comment: Alos, using equal names is bad idea. Better if it's names is "`foo[]`", for examle. Some servers (PHP for example) loads that inputs as array.

Comment: Who said I didn't want it? :) The code is far more complicated than this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [**:last**](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector

```
$( "input[name='foo']:last" ).val()
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `.last()`

```
$( "input[name='foo']" ).last().val()
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of comparison, I thought I would write out the library-less `Javascript` equivalent:

```
var lastFooValue = document.querySelector('input[name="foo"]:last-of-type').value;
```

(It's almost identical to the `jQuery`...)